# Problems with SSL and multi level subdomains

Tags: ssl, subdomain

I have a wildcard SSL from Godaddy. When I go here:

```
https://conciergelive.conciergeliveapp.com/users_session/new
```

Everything is fine. But when I go here:

```
https://es.conciergelive.conciergeliveapp.com/users_session/new
```

I get a security alert. I need the extra subdomain to determine locality. Any ideas why this does not work?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

According to [RFC 2818](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2818.txt) Http Over SSL, section 3.1:

> Names may contain the wildcard
>   character * which is considered to
>   match any single domain name component
>   or component fragment. E.g., *.a.com
>   matches foo.a.com but not
>   bar.foo.a.com

it explains why the name *.conciergeliveapp.com in the certifacte matches conciergelive.conciergeliveapp.com but not es.conciergelive.conciergeliveapp.com

Comment: The standard (as in standards track RFC) on wildcard certificate matching rules is actually RFC 6125 (section 6.4.3); RFC 2818 has only informational status. https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125.txt

Answer (score 11):

Your SSL cert is really only good for *.conciergeliveapp.com, you will need another SSL cert for *.conciergelive.conciergeliveapp.com

You can reference the RFC-2818 http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2818.txt

And checkout ServerFault for more detail:
https://serverfault.com/questions/104160/wildcard-ssl-certificate-for-second-level-subdomain