# wildcard certificate does not work for sub-domain

Tags: ssl, certificate

I have created a wildcard certificate that works for for `xxx.domain.com` but not for `aaa.bbb.domain.com`

when creating the certificate:

```
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:*.domain.com
```

but it seems to not be enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Wildcard SSL certificate matches only one level**. See

- [Problems with SSL and multi level subdomains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295521/problems-with-ssl-and-multi-level-subdomains)
- [wildcard ssl certificate does not cover www version, how do I fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860643/wildcard-ssl-certificate-does-not-cover-www-version-how-do-i-fix)
- [SSL Multilevel Subdomain Wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26744696/ssl-multilevel-subdomain-wildcard)
- https://serverfault.com/questions/296390/ssl-domain-problem-for-signed-asterisk-certificates
- https://serverfault.com/questions/645230/why-does-my-wildcard-ssl-certificate-cause-a-domain-mismatch-error-on-a-second-l
- https://serverfault.com/questions/87869/ssl-certificates-for-subdomain-example-com
- https://serverfault.com/questions/104160/wildcard-ssl-certificate-for-second-level-subdomain
- https://serverfault.com/questions/871171/cant-secure-sub-domain-with-ssl
- https://serverfault.com/questions/817255/difference-between-wild-card-ssl
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83245/ssl-cert-for-sub-domain-com-and-www-sub-domain-com
- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/158332/what-are-wildcard-certificate-limitations-in-san-extension