# Chrome showing error NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID for site with CN and Subject Alternative Name Set Correctly

Tags: certificate

Chrome shows error (NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID) when accessing https://www.unifiedportal-mem.epfindia.gov.in/memberinterface . The certificate has Common Name (CN) and Subject Alternative Name (SAN) set to *.epfindia.gov.in, so why does chrome generating the error?

I did read the [link](http://unmitigatedrisk.com/?p=381) to understand why SAN is now preferred over CN. Note that firefox also showing warning on trying to access the epfindia.gov.in link.

Here are screenshots

- Left-most shows chrome error
- Middle shows Subject in Certificate
- Right-most show Subject Alternative Name in Certificate

[image]

Comment: Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510641/wildcard-certificate-does-not-work-for-sub-domain and several more linked there.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Feel free to mark it as duplicate. So the www prefix here was causing multi-level domain causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is the www in the URL which is causing it to not match with the Certificate. https://www.unifiedportal-mem.epfindia.gov.in/memberinterface vs https://unifiedportal-mem.epfindia.gov.in/memberinterface/. The epfo passbook [site](https://passbook.epfindia.gov.in/MemberPassBook/Login) provides link to www.unifiedportal-mem.epfindia.gov.in which is a problem.

The one without www works like a charm

[image]