# Is the certificate valid for the url dev.user.svc.databaker.io

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I am planing to create a certificate for the domain `*.svc.databaker.io` and a web service, that will have the DNS name `dev.user.svc.databaker.io`.

The question is, will the certificate `*.svc.databaker.io` valid for `dev.user.svc.databaker.io`

**Update**

Assume I am going to create a certificate for DNS Zones as descripts on https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/#dns-zones. For instance,

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: ClusterIssuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-staging
spec:
  acme:
    ...
    solvers:
    - dns01:
        cloudflare:
          email: user@example.com
          apiKeySecretRef:
            name: cloudflare-apikey-secret
            key: apikey
      selector:
        dnsZones:
        - 'databaker.io'
```

Will the certificate be valid also for  `user.dev.svc.databaker.io`?

Comment: Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32510641/wildcard-certificate-does-not-work-for-sub-domain  and more linked there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, wildcards only match one label, see [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-6.4.3) for details, specifically:

```
 2.  If the wildcard character is the only character of the left-most
       label in the presented identifier, the client SHOULD NOT compare
       against anything but the left-most label of the reference
       identifier (e.g., *.example.com would match foo.example.com but
       not bar.foo.example.com or example.com).
```

Their example of how **not to match** exactly covers your use case.

A certificate with CN or SAN `*.svc.databaker.io` **will not match** `dev.user.svc.databaker.io`.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you create the certificate, it still won't match more than one label (aka: subdomain).